# Configurable child product custom attribute gets value by parent

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, catalog, custom-attributes

Is there any way to inherit custom atribute value parent to child ?

eg: i have custom attribute "test" , creating configurable product productConf with child productConf-l, changing value "test" in parent to "0" and want to set productConf-l attribute test set "0",
can any way all child products (syncronized) value same with parent ?

Actually creating backend class, in the beforeSave function set all child attribute via by object manager it works but is that any better way to do this ?